# Growing an R matrix inside a C loop

Tags: c, r, matrix

I have a routine that generates a series of data vectors, one iteration at a time. I would like to find a way to "grow" either a list or a matrix that holds these vectors. I tried to create a list,

```
PROTECT( myList = allocVector( VECSXP, 1 ) )
```

But is there a way to grow the list, by pushing a vector element in the end?

Also, I wouldn't mind using a matrix, since the vectors I generate are of the same length.

Comment: I have a couple of C++ suggestions for you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Rf_lengthgets` in `Rinternals.h`; implemented in `builtin.c:lengthgets`. The returned pointer needs to be PROTECTed, so one pattern is

```
SEXP myList;
PROTECT_INDEX ipx;
PROTECT_WITH_INDEX(myList = allocVector( VECSXP, 1 ), &ipx);
REPROTECT(mylist = Rf_lengthgets(mylist, 100), ipx);
```

If one were growing a list based on some unknown stopping condition, the approach might be like in R, with pre-allocate and fill followed by extension; the following is psuedo-code:

```
const int BUF_SIZE = 100;
PROTECT_INDEX ipx;
SEXP myList;
int i, someCondition = 1;

PROTECT_WITH_INDEX(myList=allocVector(VECSXP, BUF_SIZE), &ipx);
for (i = 0; some_condition; ++i) {
    if (Rf_length(myList) == i) {
        const int len = Rf_length(myList) + BUF_SIZE;
        REPROTECT(myList = Rf_lengthgets(mYlist, BUF_SIZE), &ipx);
    }
    PROTECT(result = some_calculation();
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(myList, i, result);           
    UNPROTECT(1);
    // set some_condition
}
Rf_lengthgets(myList, i); // no need to re-PROTECT; we're leaving C
UNPROTECT(1)
return myList;
```

This performs a deep copy of `myList`, so can become expensive and in some ways if ht emain objective to evaluate some_calculation, then it seems like it's easier and not too much less efficient to do the pre-allocate and extend operations in an R loop, calling  some_calculation and doing assignment inside the loop.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The problem with such an approach is that there is no way to "save" the variable length once I call again the C procedure. Indeed, the data vector I want to push in the list are generated in Fortran code; the only way I can save them is to push them in a list which is either created in the R environment in the first time such a data vector arrives, or is read from the R environment and pushed in the last position of the list. So perhaps my question should have been, "is there a way to push a vector in the last position of a list brought in C by the R environment"?

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you're saying; I tried to add an example, using information that can be obtained from R objects about their length.

Comment: Thank you Martin. But it should be simpler than that:
`SEXP mylist, newElement;
PROTECT( mylist = findVarInFrame( rho, install("myRList") );
// myList has length n; I want to add newElement to it and return
// it back to R
PROTECT( newElement = allocVector( REALSXP, 5 ) );
// push newElement in the end of myList
defineVar( install("myRList"), myList, rho ) );
`
Same with adding a row in a matrix that I read from R using the same method.

Comment: I wouldn't advise that. You want your C code to behave like an R function call -- creating and modifying a new object, not modifying an existing one. Maybe you want to pass the current vector in from R, but you'd still want to duplicate it before changing. Or maybe you'd just return newElement, and add that to an existing list in R.

Answer (score 7):

This is IMHO a good example of where C++ beats C hands-down.

In C++, you can use a STL container (such as vector) and easily insert elements one at a time using `push_back()`.  You never use `malloc` or `free` (or `new` and `delete`), and you never touch pointers.  There is just no way to do that in C.

As well, you can make use of the [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) interface between R and C++ which makes getting the data you have grown in C++ over to R a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you. C++ is not an option, though. I use the C code as a wrapper for Fortran, as is usual for all these procedures - in effect, I evaluate an R object in an iterative manner.

Comment: The need to wrap Fortran does not exclude use of C++.

Comment: Indeed. But I choose not to use c++ on this particular project.